# Switch programmatically audio channel from chromecast screen mirroring to bluetooth headphones

Tags: android, audio, kotlin, chromecast

My code can switch audio channel of my tablet from speakers to my connected bluetooth headphones with the following code :

```
if (bluetoothSound) {
   audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn = false
   audioManager.stopBluetoothSco()
   audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = true
   audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
   initButtonSettingLayout()
 }
 else {
   audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
   audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn = true
   audioManager.startBluetoothSco()
   audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
 }
```

But once I am screen mirroring with my chromecast, none of them work.
I need a robust way to switch audio channel.
Thank you